# how to bring up text entry dialog box in Android whilee running openGL ES 2.0

Tags: android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

I am developing an openGL ES 2.0 application on Android using NDK. I need to enter text and I wish to bring up the native virtual keyboard to enter this text. 
How can I do this ?